# Move the GridView Add button to right of delete button?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

The attached screenshot shows two images.

Is it possible to make to **Add button** and delete button align side by side as depicted by the bottom image?

We are currently using GridView to create dynamic rows and it gets bit too long helped in part by the position of the **Add button**

```
<asp:gridview ID="grvCustomers" GridLines="None" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="grvCustomers_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" Visible="false" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="custname" runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adress">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="custaddress" runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="custamount" runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add More" 
                        onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
```

[image]

Comment: There isn't any image attached

Comment: sorry. It is there now.

Comment: The Add button is in the footer. You'd have to move it to the item template for it to be in the same row as the delete button.

Comment: Thank you.

Apparently I was not using it correctly.

I will be happy to give you credit .

Answer (score 0):

I second what @ahwm said.

But also, if the goal is to add the record to the data source, couldn't you simply add the commandfield showinsertbutton="true".